# How should "The $100,000 Pyramid" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

The question https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79614/12783 is our first about the game show *The $100,000 Pyramid*. How should this be tagged?

My first guess is [the-100000-pyramid](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-100000-pyramid). However, that's pretty ugly, and if someone were to come along and ask a question about *The $20,000 Pyramid* or one of the other shows, I'm not sure we would want a separate tag since they share rules. So what should it be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a tag called [game-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-show).  I think this is sufficient for tagging any TV shows classified as "game shows".  We haven't really had many questions of that genre, I don't think every game show needs its own tag.